# How to choose the right forecast method for variable 'X' when I have some available forecast for variable 'Y' with historical data of X and Y?

Tags: regression, forecasting, matlab, k-nearest-neighbour

I have yearly historical data for variables 'X' and 'Y'. Say the time frame is 't'. In addition to available historical data, I also have the forecast data of variable 'Y' for t+1. My aim is to forecast X for t+1. The data quality is sparse. So, could someone recommend which method to start with?

X data is people connected to WiFi in a building and Y data is the number of people in the building.

Thanks

So far, I did not get any clue as to how to use the forecast Y data. So, with the historical data, I tried multivariate regression and knn search algorithm. The results were not satisfactory though! I am using MATLAB.

Comment: Can you give us some more information about the data? Its hard to give any suggestions without some more info. I can tell you that my go-to after OLS is often decision tree/random forest.

Comment: @roundsquare: Thank you for your comment. X data is people connected to WiFi and Y data is the number of people in the building.

Comment: Please put that information in your question, rather than just in the comments.

Comment: @PeterFlom: I have updated the question.